# Julia: Having a function f() containing the macro @printf, how can I access the output outside f()?

Tags: iostream, julia

In the Julia [NMF](https://github.com/JuliaStats/NMF.jl) package a `verbose` option provides information on convergence using the `@printf` macro.

How can I access this output without rewriting the `NMF` package io?

To rephrase, having a function `f()` containing the macro `@printf`, how can I access the output outside `f()`?

Answer (score 4):

This does seem like useful functionality to have: I would suggest that you file an issue with the package.

However, as a quick hack, something like the following should work:

```
oldout = STDOUT
(rd,wr) = redirect_stdout()
start_reading(rd)

# call your function here

flush_cstdio()
redirect_stdout(oldout)
close(wr)
s = readall(rd)
close(rd)
s
```

Comment: Very good, thanks! This works and I will consider making the proposal.